# ArrayList method logic issue

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to execute my `ArrayList` method but it seems that it only grabs the first data.

```java
    public class CoronavirusUpdateMain  {
    
    public static void main(String []args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println();
        Scrape sp = new Scrape();
        ArrayList<Country>countryData = sp.getCountryData();
        System.out.println(countryData);
    }
}
```

The method I'm trying to execute is `countryData` which collects all the data when I run it on a test but when I call the method in main, it only contains 1 value.

```java
    final static String url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
    static ArrayList <Country> countryData = new ArrayList<Country>();

    public static ArrayList<Country> getCountryData(){
        try {
            ArrayList<Country>countryData = new ArrayList<Country>();
             Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
             Elements table = doc.select("#main_table_countries_today");
             Elements rows = table.select("tbody").select("tr");
             int idx = 0;
             for (Element row : rows) {
                 Elements eachCountry = row.select("td");
                 Country curr = new Country();
                 curr.setId(idx++);
                 curr.setCountry(eachCountry.get(1).text());            
                 curr.setTotalCases(eachCountry.get(2).text());
                 curr.setNewCases(eachCountry.get(3).text());
                 curr.setTotalDeaths(eachCountry.get(4).text());
                 curr.setNewDeaths(eachCountry.get(5).text());
                 curr.setTotalRecovered(eachCountry.get(6).text());
                 curr.setActiveCases(eachCountry.get(7).text());
                 curr.setSeriousCases(eachCountry.get(8).text());
                 curr.setTotalCasesPerMillionPop(eachCountry.get(9).text());
                 curr.setTotalDeathsPerMillionPop(eachCountry.get(10).text());
                 curr.setTotalTests(eachCountry.get(11).text());
                 curr.setTestsPerMillion(eachCountry.get(12).text());
                 curr.setPop(eachCountry.get(13).text());                
                 countryData.add(curr);  
             }
          }catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 return null;
         }
        return countryData;
    }
```

This is the result of the main when I call the method

> [Countryidx=0, country='North America', totalCases='1,739,671', newCases='+3,575', totalDeaths='106,293', newDeaths='+351', totalRecovered='455,831', activeCases='1,177,547', seriousCases='18,422', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population='']

This is the result when I test run it in another main

> Countryidx=0, country='North America', totalCases='1,739,671', newCases='+3,575', totalDeaths='106,293', newDeaths='+351', totalRecovered='455,831', activeCases='1,177,547', seriousCases='18,422', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=1, country='Europe', totalCases='1,825,534', newCases='+10,096', totalDeaths='164,790', newDeaths='+216', totalRecovered='805,583', activeCases='855,161', seriousCases='11,117', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=2, country='South America', totalCases='488,006', newCases='+349', totalDeaths='25,493', newDeaths='+15', totalRecovered='177,003', activeCases='285,510', seriousCases='10,599', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=3, country='Asia', totalCases='848,074', newCases='+6,952', totalDeaths='25,601', newDeaths='+101', totalRecovered='488,138', activeCases='334,335', seriousCases='4,961', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=4, country='Africa', totalCases='93,444', newCases='+216', totalDeaths='2,926', newDeaths='+2', totalRecovered='36,971', activeCases='53,547', seriousCases='287', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=5, country='Oceania', totalCases='8,686', newCases='+11', totalDeaths='121', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='7,990', activeCases='575', seriousCases='10', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=6, country='', totalCases='721', newCases='', totalDeaths='15', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='651', activeCases='55', seriousCases='4', totalCasesPerMillionPop='', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=7, country='World', totalCases='5,004,136', newCases='+21,199', totalDeaths='325,239', newDeaths='+685', totalRecovered='1,972,167', activeCases='2,706,730', seriousCases='45,400', totalCasesPerMillionPop='642', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='41.7', totalTests='', testsPerMillion='', population=''
> Countryidx=8, country='USA', totalCases='1,571,018', newCases='+435', totalDeaths='93,542', newDeaths='+9', totalRecovered='361,227', activeCases='1,116,249', seriousCases='17,249', totalCasesPerMillionPop='4,749', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='283', totalTests='12,647,099', testsPerMillion='38,234', population='330,779,957'
> Countryidx=9, country='Russia', totalCases='308,705', newCases='+8,764', totalDeaths='2,972', newDeaths='+135', totalRecovered='85,392', activeCases='220,341', seriousCases='2,300', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,115', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='20', totalTests='7,500,000', testsPerMillion='51,395', population='145,927,463'
> Countryidx=10, country='Spain', totalCases='278,803', newCases='', totalDeaths='27,778', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='196,958', activeCases='54,067', seriousCases='1,152', totalCasesPerMillionPop='5,963', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='594', totalTests='3,037,840', testsPerMillion='64,977', population='46,752,753'
> Countryidx=11, country='Brazil', totalCases='271,885', newCases='', totalDeaths='17,983', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='106,794', activeCases='147,108', seriousCases='8,318', totalCasesPerMillionPop='1,280', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='85', totalTests='735,224', testsPerMillion='3,462', population='212,385,054'
> Countryidx=12, country='UK', totalCases='248,818', newCases='', totalDeaths='35,341', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='N/A', activeCases='N/A', seriousCases='1,559', totalCasesPerMillionPop='3,667', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='521', totalTests='2,772,552', testsPerMillion='40,866', population='67,845,213'
> Countryidx=13, country='Italy', totalCases='226,699', newCases='', totalDeaths='32,169', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='129,401', activeCases='65,129', seriousCases='716', totalCasesPerMillionPop='3,749', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='532', totalTests='3,104,524', testsPerMillion='51,338', population='60,471,682'
> Countryidx=14, country='France', totalCases='180,809', newCases='', totalDeaths='28,022', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='62,563', activeCases='90,224', seriousCases='1,894', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,771', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='429', totalTests='1,384,633', testsPerMillion='21,218', population='65,257,220'
> Countryidx=15, country='Germany', totalCases='177,842', newCases='+15', totalDeaths='8,193', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='156,900', activeCases='12,749', seriousCases='1,115', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,123', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='98', totalTests='3,147,771', testsPerMillion='37,584', population='83,753,585'
> Countryidx=16, country='Turkey', totalCases='151,615', newCases='', totalDeaths='4,199', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='112,895', activeCases='34,521', seriousCases='882', totalCasesPerMillionPop='1,800', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='50', totalTests='1,675,517', testsPerMillion='19,892', population='84,232,553'
> Countryidx=17, country='Iran', totalCases='124,603', newCases='', totalDeaths='7,119', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='97,173', activeCases='20,311', seriousCases='2,698', totalCasesPerMillionPop='1,486', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='85', totalTests='716,176', testsPerMillion='8,540', population='83,865,579'
> Countryidx=18, country='India', totalCases='106,886', newCases='+411', totalDeaths='3,303', newDeaths='+1', totalRecovered='42,309', activeCases='61,274', seriousCases='', totalCasesPerMillionPop='78', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='2', totalTests='2,512,388', testsPerMillion='1,823', population='1,378,418,813'
> Countryidx=19, country='Peru', totalCases='99,483', newCases='', totalDeaths='2,914', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='36,524', activeCases='60,045', seriousCases='883', totalCasesPerMillionPop='3,022', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='89', totalTests='679,582', testsPerMillion='20,645', population='32,917,154'
> Countryidx=20, country='Canada', totalCases='79,112', newCases='', totalDeaths='5,912', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='40,050', activeCases='33,150', seriousCases='502', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,098', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='157', totalTests='1,339,971', testsPerMillion='35,540', population='37,703,672'
> Countryidx=21, country='Saudi Arabia', totalCases='59,854', newCases='', totalDeaths='329', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='31,634', activeCases='27,891', seriousCases='251', totalCasesPerMillionPop='1,722', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='9', totalTests='618,084', testsPerMillion='17,787', population='34,748,812'
> Countryidx=22, country='Belgium', totalCases='55,983', newCases='+192', totalDeaths='9,150', newDeaths='+42', totalRecovered='14,847', activeCases='31,986', seriousCases='313', totalCasesPerMillionPop='4,833', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='790', totalTests='720,228', testsPerMillion='62,175', population='11,583,877'
> Countryidx=23, country='Mexico', totalCases='54,346', newCases='+2,713', totalDeaths='5,666', newDeaths='+334', totalRecovered='37,325', activeCases='11,355', seriousCases='378', totalCasesPerMillionPop='422', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='44', totalTests='185,755', testsPerMillion='1,442', population='128,773,952'
> Countryidx=24, country='Chile', totalCases='49,579', newCases='', totalDeaths='509', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='21,507', activeCases='27,563', seriousCases='876', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,596', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='27', totalTests='397,200', testsPerMillion='20,799', population='19,097,135'
> Countryidx=25, country='Pakistan', totalCases='45,898', newCases='+1,932', totalDeaths='985', newDeaths='+46', totalRecovered='13,101', activeCases='31,812', seriousCases='111', totalCasesPerMillionPop='208', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='4', totalTests='414,254', testsPerMillion='1,880', population='220,368,526'
> Countryidx=26, country='Netherlands', totalCases='44,249', newCases='', totalDeaths='5,715', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='N/A', activeCases='N/A', seriousCases='293', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,583', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='334', totalTests='302,395', testsPerMillion='17,652', population='17,130,596'
> Countryidx=27, country='Qatar', totalCases='35,606', newCases='', totalDeaths='15', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='5,634', activeCases='29,957', seriousCases='172', totalCasesPerMillionPop='12,384', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='5', totalTests='166,182', testsPerMillion='57,799', population='2,875,180'
> Countryidx=28, country='Ecuador', totalCases='34,151', newCases='', totalDeaths='2,839', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='3,457', activeCases='27,855', seriousCases='221', totalCasesPerMillionPop='1,939', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='161', totalTests='98,171', testsPerMillion='5,574', population='17,610,964'
> Countryidx=29, country='Belarus', totalCases='31,508', newCases='', totalDeaths='175', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='10,620', activeCases='20,713', seriousCases='92', totalCasesPerMillionPop='3,334', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='19', totalTests='375,076', testsPerMillion='39,692', population='9,449,669'
> Countryidx=30, country='Sweden', totalCases='30,799', newCases='', totalDeaths='3,743', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='4,971', activeCases='22,085', seriousCases='287', totalCasesPerMillionPop='3,052', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='371', totalTests='209,900', testsPerMillion='20,799', population='10,092,027'
> Countryidx=31, country='Switzerland', totalCases='30,618', newCases='', totalDeaths='1,891', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='27,700', activeCases='1,027', seriousCases='57', totalCasesPerMillionPop='3,541', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='219', totalTests='350,099', testsPerMillion='40,486', population='8,647,311'
> Countryidx=32, country='Portugal', totalCases='29,432', newCases='', totalDeaths='1,247', newDeaths='', totalRecovered='6,431', activeCases='21,754', seriousCases='101', totalCasesPerMillionPop='2,885', totalDeathsPerMillionPop='122', totalTests='662,375', testsPerMillion='64,939', population='10,199,983'

This is the updated code in the method. Static has to be removed as it doesn't change the value of the `ArrayList`, I also had to remove the 2 unnecessary return as it doesn't return the complete `ArrayList`.

```java
    public ArrayList<Country> getCountryData(){
        ArrayList<Country>countryData = new ArrayList<Country>();
        try {
        
             Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
             Elements table = doc.select("#main_table_countries_today");
             Elements rows = table.select("tbody").select("tr");
             int idx = 0;
             for (Element row : rows) {
                 Elements eachCountry = row.select("td");
                 Country curr = new Country();
                 curr.setId(idx++);
                 curr.setCountry(eachCountry.get(1).text());            
                 curr.setTotalCases(eachCountry.get(2).text());
                 curr.setNewCases(eachCountry.get(3).text());
                 curr.setTotalDeaths(eachCountry.get(4).text());
                 curr.setNewDeaths(eachCountry.get(5).text());
                 curr.setTotalRecovered(eachCountry.get(6).text());
                 curr.setActiveCases(eachCountry.get(7).text());
                 curr.setSeriousCases(eachCountry.get(8).text());
                 curr.setTotalCasesPerMillionPop(eachCountry.get(9).text());
                 curr.setTotalDeathsPerMillionPop(eachCountry.get(10).text());
                 curr.setTotalTests(eachCountry.get(11).text());
                 curr.setTestsPerMillion(eachCountry.get(12).text());
                 curr.setPop(eachCountry.get(13).text());                
                 countryData.add(curr);
              
             }
         }catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return countryData;
    }
```

Comment: You have `countryData` instance defined as `static` as well as `local`. Try removing static one and see if the behavior changes

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh

I changed it to public ArrayList<Country> getCountryData(){ but it seems that it is still the same

Comment: "This is the result when I test run it in another main" - what are you doing differently in that other main method? How are you testing your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the changes as follows:

```
//static ArrayList <Country> countryData = new ArrayList<Country>();<--- Remove this

public static ArrayList<Country> getCountryData(){
    ArrayList<Country>countryData = new ArrayList<Country>(); //<--- Move it from within the try...catch block to here
    try {        
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        //...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // return null; <--- Remove this
    }
    return countryData;
}
```

**Explanation (thanks to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910989/arraylist-method-logic-issue/61911335#comment109503300_61911335)):**

The local variable `countryData` is hiding the `static` variable of the same name but only inside the `try-block`, thus the original return `countryData()` actually returns the `static` list which is empty with the given code.

Comment: That gave a null

Comment: @Fenzox - You also have to remove `return null;`

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash still null :/

Comment: @Fenzox - I've marked the changes in the updated answer. I hope, it helps.

Comment: I'd suggest you also explain your answer a little in case someone else tries to refer to it. Just providing updated code may help immediately but also explaining why you made those changes might help readers understand and spot similar errors themselves. For example,  the local variable `countryData` is hiding the static variable of the same name but only inside the try-block, thus the original `return countryData()` actually returns the static list which should be empty given the code we have (unless some external code adds data).

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas for adding the valuable comment. I've updated the answer to incorporate it because sometimes, comments get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the list from your for loop after the first iteration itself.
       countryData.add(curr);
       return countryData;
You should return at the end of the loop after your catch statement.
This will add all the elements to the list before returning.

Comment: I got a null returned after removing the first return